# How to create a thread safe singleton in vala?

Tags: glib, vala

I want to create a thread-safe singleton instance for my vala class.

As you know, singletons may lead to [threading issues](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164929/is-the-singleton-pattern-prone-to-thread-safety-problems) if not properly implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to use the [GLib.Once](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Once.html) construct:

```
public class MyClass : Object {

    private static GLib.Once<MyClass> _instance;
     
    public static unowned MyClass instance () {
        return _instance.once (() => { return new MyClass (); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use SingleInstance Code Attribute. It does the same for you automatically!

```
[SingleInstance]
public class ExampleClass : Object {
    public int prop { get; set; default = 42; }
    public ExampleClass () {
        // ...
    }
}

int main (string[] args) {
    var a = new ExampleClass (); // the two refs
    var b = new ExampleClass (); // are the same
    b.prop += 1;
    assert (a.prop == b.prop);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that in this case you don't need to call a static function like `instance()` or `get_instance()`. Simply creating an object via `new` will give you a reference to the singleton.

Comment: And there you can find all common patterns for Vala https://github.com/design-patterns-for-humans/vala

Comment: As there is almost no info on SingleInstance in the official documentation, I'm just going to drop a link here to a discussion about it on the Vala's gitlab: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/issues/647